# scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to Integer

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm fairly new to Spark and Scala. I'm trying to call a function as a Spark UDF but I run into this error that I can't seem to resolve.

I understand that in Scala, Array and Seq aren't the same. WrappedArray is a subtype of Seq and there is implicit conversions between WrappedArray and Array but I'm not sure why that doesn't happen in the case of the UDF.

Any pointers to help me understand and resolve this is much appreciated.

Here's a snippet of the code

```
def filterMapKeysWithSet(m: Map[Int, Int], a: Array[Int]): Map[Int, Int] = {
val seqToArray = a.toArray
val s = seqToArray.toSet
m filterKeys s
}

val myUDF = udf((m: Map[Int, Int], a: Array[Int]) => filterMapKeysWithSet(m, a))

case class myType(id: Int, m: Map[Int, Int])
val mapRDD = Seq(myType(1, Map(1 -> 100, 2 -> 200)), myType(2, Map(1 -> 100, 2 -> 200)), myType(3, Map(3 -> 300, 4 -> 400)))
val mapDF = mapRDD.toDF

mapDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, m: map<int,int>]
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- m: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)

case class myType2(id: Int, a: Array[Int])
val idRDD = Seq(myType2(1, Array(1,2,100,200)), myType2(2, Array(100,200)), myType2(3, Array(1,2)) )
val idDF = idRDD.toDF

idDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, a: array<int>]
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)

import sqlContext.implicits._
/* Hive context is exposed as sqlContext */

val j = mapDF.join(idDF, idDF("id") === mapDF("id")).drop(idDF("id"))
val k = j.withColumn("filteredMap",myUDF(j("m"), j("a")))
k.show
```

Looking at the Dataframe "j" & "k", the map and array columns have the right data types.

```
j: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, m: map<int,int>, a: array<int>]
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- m: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)

k: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, m: map<int,int>, a: array<int>, filteredMap: map<int,int>]
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- m: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- filteredMap: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
```

However, an action on the Dataframe "k" that calls the UDF fails with the following error -

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 6, ip-100-74-42-194.ec2.internal): java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [I
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(basicOperators.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1865)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1865)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Try to print the schema for both the dataframe first i.e. mapDF and idDF and paste it here ! That would give us some insight !

Comment: Added Schema for the dataframe. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: just one more thing add the j schema too !

Comment: added schema for j

Comment: It is strange it says "........cannot be cast to [I".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Changing the datatype from Array[Int] to Seq[Int] in the function filterMapKeysWithSet seems to resolve the above issue.

```
def filterMapKeysWithSet(m: Map[Int, Int], a: Seq[Int]): Map[Int, Int] = {

    val seqToArray = a.toArray

    val s = seqToArray.toSet

    m filterKeys s

  }

val myUDF = udf((m: Map[Int, Int], a: Seq[Int]) => filterMapKeysWithSet(m, a))

k: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, m: map<int,int>, a: array<int>, filteredMap: map<int,int>]
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- m: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)
 |-- a: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- filteredMap: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: integer
 |    |-- value: integer (valueContainsNull = false)

+---+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+
| id|                   m|               a|         filteredMap|
+---+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+
|  1|Map(1 -> 100, 2 -...|[1, 2, 100, 200]|Map(1 -> 100, 2 -...|
|  2|Map(1 -> 100, 2 -...|      [100, 200]|               Map()|
|  3|Map(3 -> 300, 4 -...|          [1, 2]|               Map()|
+---+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+
```

So it looks like the ArrayType on Dataframe "idDF" is really a WrappedArray and not an Array - So the function call to "filterMapKeysWithSet" failed as it expected an Array but got a WrappedArray/ Seq instead (which doesn't implicitly convert to Array in Scala 2.8 and above).

Comment: Is there any way to explicitly cast the type of the Array in the Dataframe idDF before passing to the function? All array functions in spark 2.6.1 like collect_list(), collect_set() create a WrappedArray.

Comment: thats right. If there is a array types columns in datarame (eg: Array<String> ) , one shoud use sequence in the udf function as the parameter type (eg Seq[String] )

Comment: thank you sir .. worked for me too (at least for the moment :) )